# C#: Override method use inherited input

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, overriding

i have a question where I hope you can help me.

Imagine, I have a class Person and IPerson. I would like to copy IPerson into Person as follows by calling the function main:

```
private void main()
{
  IChild TheIChild = new IChild (); 
  IAdult TheIAdult = new IAdult ();
  
  Child TheChild = new Child();
  Adult TheAdult = new Adult();

  TheChild.ImportParameter(TheIChild);
  TheAdult.ImportParameter(TheIAdult);

}



public class Person
{
string hat;    
public virtual void ImportParameter(IPerson person)
{
   hat=person.hat;
}
}

public class Child: Person
{
string teat;
public override void ImportParameter(IChild child)
{
  base.ImportParameter(child);
  teat = child.teat;
}
}

public class Adult: Person
{
string cigarette;
public override void ImportParameter(IAdult adult)
{
  base.ImportParameter(adult);
  cigarette = adult.cigarette ;
}
}

public class IPerson
{
  string hat="Big hat";
}

public class IChild: IPerson
{
 string teat= "Big teat";
}


public class IAdult: IPerson
{
 string cigarette = "Big cigarette ";
}
```

However, this results in an error since the overwritten function ImportParameter (of Child and Adult) has not the same input as the parent class (Person). The input parameter is an inherited of the input parameter of the parent function.

Does the possibility exist to overwrite the function ImportParameter but provide an inherited input?

Thank you and best regards!

Greg

Comment: This is confusing. Types that start with "I" are expected to be interfaces. (`interface IPerson { }`)

Comment: `public virtual void ImportParameter<T>(T person) where T : IPerson`

Answer (score 0):

if the functions does no have the same signature - name and parameters - there is not need to override.

remove `override` from the functions. and also, set the properties as `public` to all of your "I*" classes, otherwise you will have problem due to protection level.